# Connection parameters for Microsoft SQL Server in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server with PHP

To work with a mirrored database in the sql management studio I use "ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly" in the "Additional Connection Parameters" label.

How can I set this parameter in php?

Example of how I'm connection without the parameter:

```
$serverName = "server, port";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"my_db");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it as one of the options, like so:

```
sqlsrv_connect($serverName, ['ApplicationIntent' => 'ReadOnly']);
```

Or in your case:

```
$serverName = "server, port"; 
$connectionInfo = array('Database' => 'my_db', 'ApplicationIntent' => 'ReadOnly'); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

See also the [php docs for sqlsrv_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php).

Comment: Thanks for the answer